# Timer Extension

Tags: java, javafx, timeline

I was trying to create a timer that would extend its length when a rectangle is clicked in the javafx game that I created. When either the black or red rectangle is clicked, the Timeline keyframe `Duration.millis()` method is extended by 10 seconds. For some reason, I can't extend the length of the timer to add more time to it. Is there a way to change the Timeline object to add more time when a rectangle is successfully clicked or is there another way? Thanks

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;

public class NinjaClicker extends Application {
    // integer for storing score
    int score = 0;              
    @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Bug objects
        BlackBug blackBug = new BlackBug();
        RedBug redBug = new RedBug();
        BlueBug blueBug = new BlueBug();
        GreenBug greenBug = new GreenBug(); 

        // Pane object
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#00000000;");

        // HBox Object for containing the score label, score textfield, and close button
        HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Label scoreLabel = new Label("Score:");
        TextField scoreTextField = new TextField();
        Button close = new Button("Close");
        close.setOnAction(e->{
            primaryStage.close();
        });
        scoreTextField.setPrefColumnCount(20);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(scoreLabel, scoreTextField, close);

        // Rectangle objects that represent each type of bug
        Rectangle blackRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,20,15);
        blackRectangle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        blackRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        blackRectangle.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Rectangle redRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,30,25);
        redRectangle.setFill(Color.RED);
        redRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        redRectangle.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Rectangle blueRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,40,35);
        blueRectangle.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        blueRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        blueRectangle.setStrokeWidth(2); 

        Rectangle greenRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 45);
        greenRectangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        greenRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        greenRectangle.setStrokeWidth(2);


        // Line objects    
        Line blackLine = new Line(0,0,500,500);
        blackLine.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);

        Line redLine = new Line(250, 0, 250, 500);
        redLine.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);

        Line blueLine = new Line(0,250,500,250);
        blueLine.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);

        Line greenLine = new Line(500,0,0,500);
        greenLine.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);

        // Add rectangles to pane object
        pane.getChildren().add(redRectangle);
        pane.getChildren().add(blackRectangle);
        pane.getChildren().add(greenRectangle);
        pane.getChildren().add(blueRectangle);
        pane.getChildren().add(redLine);
        pane.getChildren().add(blackLine);
        pane.getChildren().add(greenLine);
        pane.getChildren().add(blueLine);


        // Pathtransitions
        PathTransition blackPath = new PathTransition();
        blackPath.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
        blackPath.setPath(blackLine);
        blackPath.setNode(blackRectangle);
        blackPath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        blackPath.setAutoReverse(true);
        blackPath.play();

        PathTransition redPath = new PathTransition();
        redPath.setDuration(Duration.millis(8000));
        redPath.setPath(redLine);
        redPath.setNode(redRectangle);
        redPath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        redPath.setAutoReverse(true);
        redPath.play();

        PathTransition bluePath = new PathTransition();
        bluePath.setDuration(Duration.millis(11000));
        bluePath.setPath(blueLine);
        bluePath.setNode(blueRectangle);
        bluePath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        bluePath.setAutoReverse(true);
        bluePath.play();

        PathTransition greenPath = new PathTransition();
        greenPath.setDuration(Duration.millis(14000));
        greenPath.setPath(greenLine);
        greenPath.setNode(greenRectangle);
        greenPath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        greenPath.setAutoReverse(true);
        greenPath.play();

        // Rotate Transition
        RotateTransition rotate = new RotateTransition();
        rotate.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
        rotate.setByAngle(360);
        rotate.setCycleCount(500);
        rotate.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
        rotate.setAutoReverse(true);
        rotate.setNode(pane);
        rotate.play();

        // Borderpane that contains the pane and hBox objects
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(pane);
        borderPane.setBottom(hBox);

        // Place the borderPane in the scene and the scene inside the stage.
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 500, 500);  
        primaryStage.setTitle("Ninja Clicker");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Timeline object
        Timeline endTheGame = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(20000),
                ae -> gameOver()));
        endTheGame.play();
        endTheGame.setOnFinished(e->{
            primaryStage.close();
        });

        /* Event handling that removes rectangles, increases points, and increases timeline
        if either a black or red rectangle is clicked */
        blackRectangle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            pane.getChildren().remove(blackRectangle);
            score = score + blackBug.getPoints();
            endTheGame.stop();
            scoreTextField.setText("Good job! Your score is " + score);
        });

        redRectangle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            pane.getChildren().remove(redRectangle);
            score = score + redBug.getPoints();
            scoreTextField.setText("Good job! Your score is " + score);
        });

        blueRectangle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            pane.getChildren().remove(blueRectangle);
            score = score + blueBug.getPoints();
            scoreTextField.setText("Good job! Your score is " + score);
        });

        greenRectangle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
            pane.getChildren().remove(greenRectangle);
            score = score + greenBug.getPoints();
            scoreTextField.setText("Good job! Your score is " + score);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // Method to signal the end of the game
    public void gameOver() {
        // Stage for showing window
        Stage stage = new Stage();

        // BorderPane object for storing hBox and timerText. 
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
        Button closeSystem = new Button("Close");
        closeSystem.setOnAction(e->{
            System.exit(0);
        });

        hBox.getChildren().add(closeSystem);

        Text timerText = new Text("Times Up! Your score is " + score);
        pane.setCenter(timerText);
        pane.setBottom(hBox);

        // Scene in the Stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200,200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Times Up!");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a countdown variable and restructure your Timeline.

**Restructured Timeline object and countdown variable**

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(20);
endTheGame = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
        Duration.seconds(1),
        ae -> {
            atomicInteger.decrementAndGet();
            System.out.println(atomicInteger.get());
            if(atomicInteger.get() == 0)
            {
                gameOver();                
                endTheGame.stop();
                primaryStage.close();
            }
        }
));
endTheGame.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
endTheGame.play();
```

**Example of how to add more time when a rectangle is clicked:**

```
blackRectangle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
    pane.getChildren().remove(blackRectangle);
//    score = score + blackBug.getPoints();
    //endTheGame.stop();
    atomicInteger.set(atomicInteger.get() + 5);
    scoreTextField.setText("Good job! Your score is " + score);
});
```

**Full Code:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;

public class Main extends Application {
// integer for storing score
int score = 0;   
Timeline endTheGame;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
// Bug objects
//BlackBug blackBug = new BlackBug();
//RedBug redBug = new RedBug();
//BlueBug blueBug = new BlueBug();
//GreenBug greenBug = new GreenBug(); 

// Pane object
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#00000000;");

// HBox Object for containing the score label, score textfield, and close button
HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
Label scoreLabel = new Label("Score:");
TextField scoreTextField = new TextField();
Button close = new Button("Close");
close.setOnAction(e->{
    primaryStage.close();
});
scoreTextField.setPrefColumnCount(20);
hBox.getChildren().addAll(scoreLabel, scoreTextField, close);

// Rectangle objects that represent each type of bug
Rectangle blackRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,20,15);
blackRectangle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
blackRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
blackRectangle.setStrokeWidth(2);

Rectangle redRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,30,25);
redRectangle.setFill(Color.RED);
redRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
redRectangle.setStrokeWidth(2);

Rectangle blueRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,40,35);
blueRectangle.setFill(Color.BLUE);
blueRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
blueRectangle.setStrokeWidth(2); 

Rectangle greenRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 45);
greenRectangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
greenRectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
greenRectangle.setStrokeWidth(2);


// Line objects    
Line blackLine = new Line(0,0,500,500);
blackLine.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);

Line redLine = new Line(250, 0, 250, 500);
redLine.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);

Line blueLine = new Line(0,250,500,250);
blueLine.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);

Line greenLine = new Line(500,0,0,500);
greenLine.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);

// Add rectangles to pane object
pane.getChildren().add(redRectangle);
pane.getChildren().add(blackRectangle);
pane.getChildren().add(greenRectangle);
pane.getChildren().add(blueRectangle);
pane.getChildren().add(redLine);
pane.getChildren().add(blackLine);
pane.getChildren().add(greenLine);
pane.getChildren().add(blueLine);


// Pathtransitions
PathTransition blackPath = new PathTransition();
blackPath.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
blackPath.setPath(blackLine);
blackPath.setNode(blackRectangle);
blackPath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
blackPath.setAutoReverse(true);
blackPath.play();

PathTransition redPath = new PathTransition();
redPath.setDuration(Duration.millis(8000));
redPath.setPath(redLine);
redPath.setNode(redRectangle);
redPath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
redPath.setAutoReverse(true);
redPath.play();

PathTransition bluePath = new PathTransition();
bluePath.setDuration(Duration.millis(11000));
bluePath.setPath(blueLine);
bluePath.setNode(blueRectangle);
bluePath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
bluePath.setAutoReverse(true);
bluePath.play();

PathTransition greenPath = new PathTransition();
greenPath.setDuration(Duration.millis(14000));
greenPath.setPath(greenLine);
greenPath.setNode(greenRectangle);
greenPath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
greenPath.setAutoReverse(true);
greenPath.play();

// Rotate Transition
RotateTransition rotate = new RotateTransition();
rotate.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
rotate.setByAngle(360);
rotate.setCycleCount(500);
rotate.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
rotate.setAutoReverse(true);
rotate.setNode(pane);
rotate.play();

// Borderpane that contains the pane and hBox objects
BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
borderPane.setCenter(pane);
borderPane.setBottom(hBox);




// Place the borderPane in the scene and the scene inside the stage.
Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 500, 500);  
primaryStage.setTitle("Ninja Clicker");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
primaryStage.show();

// Timeline object
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(20);
endTheGame = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
        Duration.seconds(1),
        ae -> {
            atomicInteger.decrementAndGet();
            System.out.println(atomicInteger.get());
            if(atomicInteger.get() == 0)
            {
                gameOver();                
                endTheGame.stop();
                primaryStage.close();
            }
        }
));
endTheGame.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
endTheGame.play();

/* Event handling that removes rectangles, increases points, and increases timeline
if either a black or red rectangle is clicked */
blackRectangle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
    pane.getChildren().remove(blackRectangle);
//    score = score + blackBug.getPoints();
    //endTheGame.stop();
    atomicInteger.set(atomicInteger.get() + 5);
    scoreTextField.setText("Good job! Your score is " + score);
});

redRectangle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
    pane.getChildren().remove(redRectangle);
    //score = score + redBug.getPoints();
    atomicInteger.set(atomicInteger.get() + 5);
    scoreTextField.setText("Good job! Your score is " + score);
});

blueRectangle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
    pane.getChildren().remove(blueRectangle);
    //score = score + blueBug.getPoints();
    scoreTextField.setText("Good job! Your score is " + score);
    atomicInteger.set(atomicInteger.get() + 5);
});

greenRectangle.setOnMouseClicked(e ->{
    pane.getChildren().remove(greenRectangle);
    //score = score + greenBug.getPoints();
    scoreTextField.setText("Good job! Your score is " + score);
    atomicInteger.set(atomicInteger.get() + 5);
});




}

public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);

}

// Method to signal the end of the game
public void gameOver() {
// Stage for showing window
Stage stage = new Stage();

// BorderPane object for storing hBox and timerText. 
BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
Button closeSystem = new Button("Close");
closeSystem.setOnAction(e->{
    System.exit(0);
});

hBox.getChildren().add(closeSystem);

Text timerText = new Text("Times Up! Your score is " + score);
pane.setCenter(timerText);
pane.setBottom(hBox);

// Scene in the Stage
Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200,200);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setTitle("Times Up!");
stage.show();




}

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! The code worked, and it records the time change for the game. Thanks again!